# Tracking an offline event in Google Analytics (or something else?) and associating it to a user

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a phone system that's reporting to me real time when a user calls in.

Let's say I've got a webpage with unique phone number per client; is there any way of simulating in Analytics, or some other platform; another click/event from that user that would indiciate that they've called our system.

I effectively want to be able to 'continue' a users session on my webpage (throwing an event) without using that persons webbrowser, but from my server. I can only imagine that this would require capturing/setting some unique session id or Google Analytics cookie.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole market of phone tracking solutions that are suited for just this.

You can peruse them in the [Google Analytics Application Gallery's Phone Tracking](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/results?category=Phone%20Call%20Tracking) section.

You can [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359650/can-you-upload-data-to-the-google-analytics-api/5413910#5413910) to explain how they (generally) work.

Comment: I need to use my own numbers - I was going to match web hits to the number and the approximate time it hit my switch - not perfect; but far better than what I've got.

Comment: " generate __utm.gif calls with the relevant campaign and user data appended" -- what user data and campaign data would I need to store to generate those requests?

Comment: I just did some research --- couldn't I store the cookie that was being set when they landed on my page and use that when making the _utm request; so I would be able to see that users landing on x page ended up either exiting or going to /phonecall/number in the GA interface? (i.e. associating the cookie of the user with their call)?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if you knew the user's session id you could query this api with the same user agent etc, session id etc..

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

All theory though.

Unless i'm not understanding your question.